# Custom TextView with mirrored canvas trims the text when scrolled

Tags: java, android, textview, android-canvas

I have a custom TextView with overridden onDraw() in which I mirror the text like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int cx = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    int cy = this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    canvas.save();
        if(mirrored)
        {
            canvas.scale(1f, -1f, cx, cy);
        }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Now I want to scroll this mirrored canvas vertically with repeatable .scrollBy(0, -1) method in my activity. 
However, when I scroll the text it is getting trimmed from top: 
[scroll1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBslp.jpg) [scroll2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZi3e.jpg)

Probably something happens in the TextView method bringPointIntoView(int offset) or bringTextIntoView().

Is there a quick fix to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, for anybody interested I fixed this by setRotation(180) for text view and then mirroring the canvas by the X axis. Then my onDraw method became like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int cx = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    int cy = this.getMeasuredHeight() /2;
    canvas.save();
        if(mirrored)
        {
            canvas.scale(-1f, 1f, cx, cy);
            setRotation(180);
        }
    else
        {
            setRotation(0);
        }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

This way the scrollBy method works fine for either direction.